# Import issue on Polymer 3 upgrade

Tags: polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

i converted my app from polymer 2 to polymer 3 as per this [polymer documentation](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/upgrade) using modilizer. Post conversion done the cleanup and fixed import, 404 errors and other issues manually. But still i am getting issue/error  on import, getting below error on console.

`Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

In some places i fixed by giving relative path like this `../../node_modules/` but once i fixed this issue it show same kind error inside node_module folder files.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer-fn.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "video/mp2t". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I am using express.js so used to start app by `node index.js` will not use `polymer serve` command. Is this causing this import issue ? Could someone tell me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: If you installed package with npm, `package.json` will be handled (no need to use full path) but when you serve it use `--npm flag`  like: `polymer serve --npm` if the package is not in package.json, then address it with full path.